# Unable to maximize a QMainWindow

Tags: qt, qt4

Normally I can simply click the maximize button of a QMainWindow to maximize it. However, with this simple project wrapped around my fairly involved GUI, the maximize button does nothing:

http://daviddoria.com/Uploads/qt/Maximize/

Can anyone explain why this ui file would not allow me to maximize the window? I have checked all of the items MaximumSize and they are all allowed to expand.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It works for me on Windows 7. What platform are you on?

Comment: It's working for me there as well. The only thing that is weird is that the screen is *really* tall, so that even maximized it doesn't fit on my screen, causing the top to be cut off. But it still responds to the maximize button and does its best.

Comment: Just tried it on Ubuntu 11.10 with both Gnome3 and Unity, worked fine.

Comment: Do you think there could be some driver problem? Or I am using "gnome fallback" - could there be a problem with that?

Comment: Also, even in QtDesigner, I can't make it shorter than 1033 pixels - what is causing that constraint?

Comment: Another symptom - I can't drag the window to the top of my display - it gets probably about 50 - 100 pixels below the top of the rest of the windows and then "sticks"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed KDE and it works fine. I had tried it on two different systems with gnome. I'd still like to hear an explanation if anyone has one, but at least I know it's not something wrong with the Qt code.